# Pandas: edit time column when creating a dataframe from different csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a single dataframe from two or three csv file that are like this:

**first.csv**

```
time       duration   text
00:00:00   00:00:00   some_text 1
00:00:02   00:00:02   some_text 2
00:00:04   00:00:02   some_text 3
```

**second.cv**

```
time       duration   text
00:00:00   00:00:00   some_text A
00:00:01   00:00:01   some_text B
00:00:05   00:00:04   some_text C
```

**Example of expected output**:

In this case at the 00:00:00 time of the second file is added one second and the times are recalculated to continue the one of the first file

```
time       duration   text
00:00:00   00:00:00   some_text 1
00:00:02   00:00:02   some_text 2
00:00:04   00:00:02   some_text 3
00:00:05   00:00:01   some_text A
00:00:06   00:00:01   some_text B
00:00:10   00:00:04   some_text C
```

I'm merging the files like this:

```
df_list = []

for file in file_list:
    path_file = f"F:/data/draft_data/{file}"
    df = pd.read_csv(path_file, sep=";")
    df_list.append(df)

completed_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)                
completed_df.to_csv(f"F:/data/complete_data/{file}_completed.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', sep=';', index=False)
```

But I want the second file to not start the time at 00:00:00, but from the last time of the first file so, in this case, from 00:00:04 and to edit all the successive time and duration columns according to this. How can I do so? The 00:00:00 time row in the second file can be merged in the last row of the first file if it is a problem.
Thank you!

Comment: you can merge it yes , but you will lose the information in the second file before 00:15, it 's not  important to you ?

Comment: please provide your raw data as text as well as your expected output, I think what you need is to specify `keys` when you concat your dataframes and then conditionally drop duplicates, but easier if you provide a sample of what you need. If you follow the guidance here [mcve] I'll gladly change my downvote to up.

Comment: @Umar.H thanks for the advice, I did as suggested.

Comment: @RanA Unofortunly it is important to me to not lose any information

Comment: Can you explain how the last record jumps to 00:00:10 from 00:00:05?

Comment: @Umar.H I was thinking that maybe it could be possible to start a new time count based on the last time in the first file and then just add the previous time to get a new one

Comment: I think we need more defined business rules, @KomeGognome as a rule of thumb the person answering the question should not try to guess what your requirement is, just provide a solution.

Comment: @Umar.H Thank you anyway. I'll will just ask for help some other site, maybe they will know how to add the time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

before concatenating your dataframe list do something like:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_list)):
    df_list[i].time += df_list[i - 1].time.max()
```

Comment: it's not looping over a dataframe, df_list is a list of dataframes

Comment: my fault John, apologies!

Comment: no problem at all!